# Javascript Regex to test if string has only numbers on separated lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to test if string (from html textarea) has only numbers separated by new lines, leading/trailing spaces are allowed also.

I tried the following :

```
/^\d\n+$/.test(val);
```

and

```
/^(?=.*\d)[\d ][\n ]+$/.test(val)
```

Both did not work.

Comment: Where exactly are the spaces allowed? Can a line have spaces in between digit characters, or do you mean that leading/trailing spaces on a line are OK?

Comment: Why not `/^[\d\n\s]+$/`?

Comment: @RobG don't need the `\n`, `\s` matches it already.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes leading/trailing only.

Comment: @RobG. numbers separated with spaces on one line are not allowed.

Comment: Can you add some valid and invalid samples?

Comment: So you only want digits followed by one or more new lines, and spaces followed by one or more newlines, but not digits and spaces followed by newlines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
(?: *\d+ *(?:\n|$))+$
```

to repeat a group that includes zero or more spaces, followed by digits, followed by more spaces, followed by either a newline or the end of the string.

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.onkeyup = () => {
  const { value } = textarea;
  textarea.style.backgroundColor =
    /^(?: *\d+ *(?:\n|$))+$/.test(value)
    ? '#c0ffb7'
    : '#ffb7b7';
};
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>1234
432
44431</textarea>
```

Note that `\s`, while it might seem tempting to use initially, may refer to *any* sort of whitespace character, including a literal space and a newline - so, to be as specific as possible, use literal spaces in your regex to ensure you only match literal spaces when you want (and use `\n` to match newlines, of course).

Comment: How to allow empty lines ?

Comment: Repeat digits with `*` (zero or more) instead of `+` (one or more)

Comment: still does not allow multiple empty lines

Comment: Sure it does, I did check it, just replace the digit's `+` with the `*`